# How to set an element to window width without using code?

Tags: css

The element's immediate parent is an element that has width that can be wider than the window width.

I would like my element containing paragraphs of text to not require horizontal scrolling, ie its width should be automatically adjusted to the window width.

I can do it with a couple of lines of jQuery code, but can it be done by CSS alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `vw` to get an approximate window width (its not always the window width, but 99% of the time this will work). Only CSS3, though. The units `vh`and `vw` act like percentage of the viewport size. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length

Heres an example:

```
div { width: 100vw; } /* This div will be exactly the width of your viewport, or browser window (most of the time)*/
```

Comment: Thanks.  Good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative positioning whenever possible, any large child elements should be equal to the parent. But you can always absolutely position it:

```
.someElement{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Useful article: [set an element to window width with CSS only](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/100-height-layout-using-css/)